# Change permission of Static Azure Files

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-files

Recently I configured Azure Files provisioned statically according to this manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume I have run my application on a pod and mounted Azure Files to it. Unfortunately, when I try to create some file on this Azure Files storage from my application, I get java.io.IOException: Permission denied... Is there any way to change permissions of this Azure Files? Below is the yaml file of my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: vm-wojtek
spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 1
            maxUnavailable: 1
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: vm-wojtek
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: vm-wojtek
                  image: <image_name>
                  ports:
                  - containerPort: 8080
                  - containerPort: 8443
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  volumeMounts:
                  - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"
                    name: volume
                    readOnly: false
            volumes:
                - name: volume
                  azureFile:
                      secretName: azure-secret
                      shareName: vm-share
                      readOnly: false
```

**EDIT:**

Below is the output of *kubectl get pod  -o yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2019-03-01T07:08:29Z
  generateName: vm-wojtek-7674c7b54d-
  labels:
    app: vm-wojtek
    pod-template-hash: "3230736108"
  name: vm-wojtek-7674c7b54d-js6d6
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: vm-wojtek-7674c7b54d
    uid: d12ee2d5-3bf0-11e9-a82b-aaf390a8b6f0
  resourceVersion: "60801"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/vm-wojtek-7674c7b54d-js6d6
  uid: d1329b70-3bf0-11e9-a82b-aaf390a8b6f0
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR
      value: vm-tf-agent-b84257d1.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io
    - name: KUBERNETES_PORT
      value: tcp://vm-tf-agent-b84257d1.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443
    - name: KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP
      value: tcp://vm-tf-agent-b84257d1.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443
    - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
      value: vm-tf-agent-b84257d1.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io
    image: ...
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: vm-wojtek
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 8443
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/azure
      name: volume
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-n2vjm
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  nodeName: aks-default-36880111-0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret
      shareName: vm-share
    name: volume
  - name: default-token-n2vjm
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-n2vjm
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-03-01T07:08:29Z
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-03-01T07:10:31Z
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2019-03-01T07:08:29Z
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://17781db099f449df1b56e53b358021c06f7e140f9610d9d09bb4cf366956c687
    image: vmrdacr.azurecr.io/vm-2.0.4:v11
    imageID: ...
    lastState: {}
    name: vm-wojtek
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: 2019-03-01T07:10:31Z
  hostIP: 10.240.0.4
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.244.0.9
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: 2019-03-01T07:08:29Z
```

Comment: Hi, are you using PodSecuriyPolicy?

Comment: can you run `kubctl get pod $POD_NAME -o yaml`?